# Mathematica crashes when doing an integral with real numbers

Tags: crash

```
Integrate[Tan[t + 1], t]
```

> -Log[Cos[1 + t]]

```
Integrate[Tan[1.0 t + 1], t]
```

The second input causes Mathematica 11.3 to hang, requiring one to quit the Kernel

Comment: Indeed.  Same problem on my Mac laptop (v. 11.3.0).  Weird.

Comment: If you find a bug, report it to Wolfram. Please do not use StackExchange as a bug tracker. Problems won't get fixed unless you report them directly to Wolfram.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: No, it's a statement to the fact that Wolfram should be making basic software work instead of trying to be all things to all people. There are a lot of inefficiencies and flaws in Mathematica, often worse in newer versions, but on this forum people are just happy talking about workarounds.

Comment: Interestingly the problematic integral works fine in the Kernel.

Comment: No, on my windows laptop if I start Kernel directly, it also crashes. Also crashes WalframAlpha. I was going to see if on an older version of Mathematica it might work

Comment: What worked for me was Integrate[1.0 Tan[t+1],t] and not Integrate[Tan[t+1.0],t]. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Works fine in Mathematica v 4.1

Comment: Version 10.0 returns Holonomic`HolonomicIndefiniteIntegrate[Tan[1 + 1. x], x] while version 10.4 crashes the Kernel as well.

Comment: Report it to Wolfram?

Comment: I have of course reported this to Wolfram Tech support already. But if I were you (I mean people who frequent this forum), I would have a "Hall of shame" for the most egregious bugs, flaws, and inefficiencies of Mathematica. Public shaming on social media is the way to get problems solved these days.

Comment: "Public shaming"? That's precious. Note that MSE is not "social media", it's a technical forum.

Comment: It's more of a "Dear Leader" kind of technical forum than I have ever encountered :)

Comment: You are welcome to start your own "hall of shame". [Others have](http://www.cas-testing.org/). SE is not the place.

Comment: Despite the fact that this discussion seems to have spiralled: This bug no longer happens on version 12.0.